# Sort array, pair numbers first in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array of ints, even numbers first and then odd numbers.

Say I have `Array[10]={2,4,3,11,0,12,88,99,111,-15}`.

I want it to end up like this: `0, 2, 4, 12, 88, -15, 3, 11, 99, 111`

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
  for(j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
    if(Array[i] % 2 != 0) {
      Array[j] = Array[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I'm lost. I have no idea how to proceed beyond that.

Comment: try to do a simple sort first, smallest to largest.

Comment: that I can do. but how to get pairs first then odds.

Comment: once you have a simple sort, how could you push the first odd value all the way to the end of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure what "pairs first" means?

Comment: do you mean even numbers first, then odd numbers ? i don't see any pairs

Comment: Yes pair/impair are french (at least) words for even/odd...

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I meant even numbers first then odd numbers. I'm french.

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense. And `4` disappeared in the expected result. You need to describe the "sorting" process you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Take any sort algorithm but use a *special* comparison : a even number should considered as lesser than a odd one, and if two numbers have the same parity then use standard comparison. Something like:

```
lessthan(a,b):
  if (a%2==b%2)  // same parity
    return a<b   // then is a < b ?
  else
    return a%2==0 // else, is a even ?
```

Comment: a C sort would usually return `a - b` to sort numbers, not `a < b`

Comment: @Alnitak Subtracting values is always a mistake when sorting integers with qsort.

Comment: @this overflow?  right - google suggests yes - good point.   In an event, my point stands that idiomatic C sort functions use -1, 0, 1, not a < test

Comment: @Alnitak Yes. Undefined for signed values. For unsigned wraps and gives incorrect results.

Comment: OP wants to implements his own sorting, not to use a `*sort` function, so from an algorithmic point of view, he just needs a boolean comparator.

Comment: I don't think this algorithm is _quite_ correct (in the second branch)

Comment: @Alnitak It is clearly pseudo code. OP can figure out the details.

Comment: @Alnitak If parity is different then if a is even it is the minimum, isn't it?

Comment: Right - I figured out the problem - with negative numbers in C, `n % 2` is 0 or -1, not 0 or 1, so comparing e.g. -15 % 2 with 9 % 2 will fail, incorrectly.  Also, I think you may have the major/minor sort orders the wrong way around.

Comment: OK, your sort orders are actually correct, but the slightly inverted logic is non-intuitive.  When comparing multiple fields in my experience it's more common for the first branch to be a `!=` test, where the branch returns the result of comparing on the major sort term, and then the fallthrough branch (when parity is the same in this case) then performs the minor sort test (i.e. a < b).  This version puts the minor comparison first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the standard library function *qsort*. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

static int Odd(int n)
{
    return n % 2 != 0;
}


static int Order(const void *xPtr, const void *yPtr)
{
    int x, y, result;

    x = *((int *) xPtr);
    y = *((int *) yPtr);

    if (! Odd(x) && Odd(y)) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (Odd(x) && ! Odd(y)) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (x < y) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (x > y) {
        result = 1;
    } else {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {2, 4, 3, 11, 0, 12, 88, 99, 111, -15};
    int i;

    qsort(a, LEN(a), sizeof a[0], Order);

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(a); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a first pass separating numbers into odd and even numbers. You now have two arrays. Sort them, them reassemble the two arrays into one.

```
void sort(int *, int);

int main() {
  int Array[10]={2,4,3,11,0,12,88,99,111,-15};
  int i, n=0, k=0, x=0, y=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if(Array[i]%2==0) {
      n++;
    } else {
      k++;
    }
  }
  int ArrEven[n], ArrOdd[k];
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if(Array[i]%2==0) {
      ArrEven[x++]=Array[i];
    } else {
      ArrOdd[y++]=Array[i];
    }
  }
  sort(ArrEven, n);
  sort(ArrOdd, k);
  x=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    Array[i]=ArrEven[i];
  }
  for(i=0;i<k;i++) {
    Array[i+n]=ArrOdd[i];
  }

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", Array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

void sort(int *array, int n) {
  for (int c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
    for (int d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) {
        int swap = array[d];
        array[d] = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To separate odd and even numbers. Easiest way. See code.

Comment: You can do it in the same array.

Comment: Why don't you put up your answer then?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of C's standard `qsort` function, but provide a custom comparator [indirectly based on Jean-Baptiste's answer]:

```
int evenoddsort(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int ai = *(const int *)a;
    int bi = *(const int *)b;
    int ar = abs(ai % 2);
    int br = abs(bi % 2);

    if (ar != br) {
        return ar - br;  /* even is "less than" odd */
    } else {
        return (ai < bi) ? -1 : (ai > bi) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
qsort(Array, 10, sizeof(int), evenoddsort);
```